# facebook checkin permission error

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk, android-facebook

In my application I am trying to checkin with specific location.

But everytime I have this error

```
{Response:  responseCode: 403, graphObject: null, error: {HttpStatus: 403, errorCode: 200, errorType: OAuthException, errorMessage: (#200) Requires extended permission: publish_actions}, isFromCache:false}
```

I am do sure that I put publish_actions permission in my permission list.

What I did wrong here? and why I have such of error everytime?

Here is my code:

```
 private Session.StatusCallback statusCallback = new SessionStatusCallback();
    private class SessionStatusCallback implements Session.StatusCallback {
        @Override
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
            if (session.isOpened()){
                checkIn(session);
                PrefsCacheManager.getInstance().putInCashe("accessToken" , session.getAccessToken());
            }
        }
    }

    private UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper;
    private LocationManager locationManager;
    private Location lastKnownLocation;
    private UiLifecycleHelper lifecycleHelper;
    private Location pickPlaceForLocationWhenSessionOpened = null;
    private static final int PLACE_ACTIVITY = 1;
    private String mPlaceId;
    private static final Location LOCATION = new Location("") {{}};

    private Session.StatusCallback callback = new Session.StatusCallback() {
        @Override
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state,
                         Exception exception) {
        }
    };

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(this, callback);
        uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        lifecycleHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(this, new Session.StatusCallback() {
            @Override
            public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
                onSessionStateChanged(session, state, exception);
            }
        });
        lifecycleHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ensureOpenSession();
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        init();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mTracker.activityStart(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        mTracker.activityStop(this);
    }

    private boolean ensureOpenSession() {
        if (Session.getActiveSession() == null ||
                !Session.getActiveSession().isOpened()) {
            Session.openActiveSession(this, true, new Session.StatusCallback() {
                @Override
                public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
                    onSessionStateChanged(session, state, exception);
                }
            });
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data, new FacebookDialog.Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookDialog.PendingCall pendingCall, Exception error, Bundle data) {
                Toast.makeText(FacebookCheckIn.this, getString(R.string.fb_share_failed), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onComplete(FacebookDialog.PendingCall pendingCall, Bundle data) {
            }
        });
        lifecycleHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == PLACE_ACTIVITY && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
            displaySelectedPlace(resultCode);
        } else if (requestCode == PLACE_ACTIVITY && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED){
            finish();
        }
    }

    private void displaySelectedPlace(int resultCode) {
        String results = "";
        SmartBonusApplication application = (SmartBonusApplication) getApplication();

        GraphPlace selection = application.getSelectedPlace();
        if (selection != null) {
            GraphLocation location = selection.getLocation();
            mPlaceId = selection.getId();
            checkFacebookSession();

        }
    }

    private void setLocation() {
        try {
            LOCATION.setLatitude(mBrench.getLat());
            LOCATION.setLongitude(mBrench.getLng());
            startPickPlaceActivity(LOCATION);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            onError(ex);
        }
    }
    private void onError(Exception exception) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Error").setMessage(exception.getMessage()).setPositiveButton("OK", null);
        builder.show();
    }

    private void checkFacebookSession() {
        final  String[] PERMISSION_ARRAY_READ = {"publish_actions" , "user_checkins"};
        final List<String> permissionList = Arrays.asList(PERMISSION_ARRAY_READ);
        new Session.NewPermissionsRequest(FacebookCheckIn.this, permissionList);
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        if (session != null){
            if (!session.isOpened() && !session.isClosed()) {
                session.openForRead(new Session.OpenRequest(this).setCallback(statusCallback));
            }else {
                Session.openActiveSession(this, true, statusCallback);
            }
        } else {
            Session.openActiveSession(this, true, statusCallback);
        }
    }

    private void checkIn(final Session pSession) {
        Bundle params = new Bundle();
        if (pSession.getAccessToken() != null) {
            params.putString("place", String.valueOf(mPlaceId));
            params.putString("message", mBrench.getCompany() + " " + mBrench.getAddress());
            params.putString("coordinates", "{\"longitude\":" + mBrench.getLng() + ",\"latitude\":" + mBrench.getLat() + "}");
            Request.Callback callback6 = new Request.Callback() {
                public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                    checkInSuccess();
                }
            };
            Request request6 = new Request(pSession, "me/checkins", params, HttpMethod.POST, callback6);
            RequestAsyncTask task6 = new RequestAsyncTask(request6);
            task6.execute();
        }
    }

    private void checkInSuccess() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(FacebookCheckIn.this, CheckinSuccessActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("branche", mBrench);
        intent.putExtra("type", VKONTAKTE);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
        overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        finish();
        overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
    }

    private void init() {
        mTracker = EasyTracker.getInstance(this);
        mBrench = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("branche");
        setLocation();
    }

    private void onSessionStateChanged(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        if (pickPlaceForLocationWhenSessionOpened != null && state.isOpened()) {
            Location location = pickPlaceForLocationWhenSessionOpened;
            pickPlaceForLocationWhenSessionOpened = null;
            startPickPlaceActivity(location);
        }
    }

    private void startPickPlaceActivity(Location location) {
        if (ensureOpenSession()) {
            SmartBonusApplication application = (SmartBonusApplication) getApplication();
            application.setSelectedPlace(null);
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, PickPlaceActivity.class);
            PickPlaceActivity.populateParameters(intent, location, null);
            startActivityForResult(intent, PLACE_ACTIVITY);
        } else {
            pickPlaceForLocationWhenSessionOpened = location;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you added the permission `publish_actions` later in the code? Also, while login do you see the extended permission box saying *"this app would like to post on your behalf"*?

Comment: I don't see any box. I added publish_actions permission when I want to do checkin post

Answer (score 0):

<strike>You must have added the permission later. and since the session has already been created it's not asking for the `publish_action` permission.</strike>

So, destroy the session by logging-out of the facebook and then login again; or remove the application from your [settings](https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=applications) and then try. This way, it will ask for the publishing permission and you'll be able to publish successfully!

---

**Edit:**

Publishing with /checkins is now deprecated. Check - [`/{user-id}/checkins`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/checkins/#publish)

You have to use the [Open Graph](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/) now to publish stories with location.

Comment: you mean I have to change me/checkins by user-id/checkins ?

Comment: Nope. `/me/checkins` and `/userid/checkins` and the same things. I'm saying that you cannot post the checking using this now. This has been dprectated. You have to use the open graph stories to publish a location. Check out the developers site for tutorials

Answer (score 0):

You have to use

```
POST /{user_id}/feed
```

as described here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/post#publishing

There you can add the place_id as parameter.